# How we can get top current 24 hours records other left all records below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table `Employee` and one column in this table is `Date`

Date column value is like this:

```
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-20 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-21 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180
```

I want to get records like this:

```
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-20 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-21 05:33:27.180,
2018-05-19 05:33:27.180
```

Please help me

Comment: unclear question

Comment: dbms name please?

Comment: I want to current last 24 hours records on top and after that other records

Comment: Nice.  What database are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, something else) ?

Comment: sql server database

Comment: Please give the query you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try ordering using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN [date] >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    [date];
```

This would place records from the last 24 hours on top, sorted ascending by date, followed by records older than 24 hours on bottom, also sorted ascending by date.

Answer (score 2):

use order by

```
 select t.* from your_table t
 order by date desc
```

Comment: Please look at OP's output. Doesn't match what you are producing.

Comment: @MayankPorwal But what is she asks is answered by his query

Comment: @SanalSunny agreed. Then the problem is with the output pasted by OP.

Comment: @MayankPorwal That might be a typo.Also in the comment, she has acknowledged to the answer